# From the below tables, I need to find out who ordered ALL products whose price>4000 using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to find out who ordered ALL products whose price>4000 using MySQL. I created a table with customers and products for price >4000. But not able to go further from there

```
Select p.name as Product_name, p.price, c.name as Customer_name 
from products as p
Left Join order_details as od On p.product_id = od.product_id
Left Join orders_0 as o On od.order_id = o.order_id
Left Join customers as c On o.customer_id = c.customer_id
Where p.price > 4000
```

This is where I am now. If you see the table, there's no one who ordered ALL products whose price is more than 4000

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/R6VMjs2VnsdwPnorY77pj/0)

Comment: I am not even sure if this is where I should be at all (in the code)!

Comment: don't paste table information as screenshots.  It's difficult to read and makes reproductions impossible.  Instead show us the `create table` output so we can create it ourselves , or create a DB Fiddle .

Comment: Added the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT c.name AS Customer_name
FROM customers AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT p.product_id
    FROM products AS p
    WHERE p.price > 4000
    EXCEPT
    SELECT p2.product_id
    FROM products AS p2
    JOIN order_details AS od ON p2.product_id = od.product_id
    JOIN orders_0 AS o ON od.order_id = o.order_id
    WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
);
```

The subquery inside the **NOT EXISTS** clause selects all the product_ids of the products with a price greater than 4000 from the **products** table.

The outer query selects the names of the customers from the **customers** table where there is no product_id in the subquery result set, which means the customer ordered all the products whose price is greater than 4000.

Comment: Thanks for this, Dulan. But this gives following error: Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT SELECT p2.product_id FROM products AS p2 JOIN order_details A' at line 7. I think the issue is Db Fiddle is not recognizing "EXCEPT"

Comment: Then try this one also, I think this might solve the issue
`SELECT c.name AS Customer_name
FROM customers AS c
JOIN orders_0 AS o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_details AS od ON o.order_id = od.order_id
JOIN products AS p ON od.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.price > 4000
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM products 
    WHERE price > 4000
);`

Comment: @DulanJayawickrama: You can (and should) use [edit] to make improvements to you answer, and you should not post those in a comment.

Comment: Thanks again, Dulan. But in this case, the result gives no results even when I have edited the DDL to make a customer buy all the products that are >4,000 :(     https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcd95aap3GVXU61MfQ5zzq/0

Comment: `Rane Smith` is returned when I test it (which is correct)  see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcd95aap3GVXU61MfQ5zzq/0

Comment: Thanks Luuk. Not sure if it's any issue with fiddle here, it shows no answer for me :(

Comment: I think I forgot to click `update`, so my changes did not show in the previous fiddle , the correct fiddle, with my change is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcd95aap3GVXU61MfQ5zzq/1, on the left side i added a line with comment `-- LINE ADDED TO GET ALL prdocucts>4000 ON ORDER 4`

Comment: Thanks for this. But this gives customers who bought the products whose price is greater than 4k. Is there a way we can get the customer name only if they have purchased ALL the products that are >4k?

Comment: @JobinTensingT: Please ask a NEW question, with a complete example, with input, and expected output.  (Because, IMHO, the give query in this answer is doing what you asked in your question )

Comment: @Luuk oh! I'm sorry. I'll edit the answer as in comments. (what did work for you? my original answer or the one in comments)

Comment: @DulanJayawickrama: It is unclear because OP (=Jobin) is asking a question in comment ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76749316/from-the-below-tables-i-need-to-find-out-who-ordered-all-products-whose-price4/76749360?noredirect=1#comment135338075_76749360)), and I think that already has been answered (by you).   It is unclear (to me) why your answer is not accepted.

Comment: @Luuk yes, that's why i'm confused too

Comment: Ok. I will create a new question with expected output. I had given "ALL" before "products>4k" to mention that the customer in result should buy ALL products > 4k. Not ANY product >4K